# How do I find the left of the smallest number in a column

Tags: google-sheets

So the cell will say bamboo because the lowest amount in the column is 662

https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELbpE.jpg

I know how to find the lowest amount with =SMALL(B2:B17, 2)
and how to find the left of the cell with =INDIRECT("RC[-1]",FALSE)
But I can't use them together

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=FILTER(A:A; B:B=MIN(B:B))
```